# Can't load images passed on to a child component as a prop by parent component in a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web-deployment, react-props

I am working on a project using React. This is the file structure of my project

- public

  - index.html
- src

  - App.js
  - images

    - facebook.png
    - image.PNG
    - linkedin.png
    - profile.png
    - twitter.png
  - Profile Intro

    - profileIntro.js
  - data

    - data.js

In my App.js, I am importing my data.js file and passing the data I get from it to the child component profileIntro,js as a prop.

Here is **data.js**

```
const user = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Amelia Everleigh",
        displayPicture: "./images/profile.png",
        coverImage: "./images/image.png",
        bio: "Writer, Thinker, Human. Unapologetic feminist. Fan of incomplete sentences. Writer & content marketing speacilist at Skillly. Freelance Writer for Hire.",
        city: "Delhi",
        country: "India",
        email: "commonstartup@gmail.com",
        facebookId: "https://www.facebook.com/yash.sethia.12/",
        twitterId: "https://twitter.com/YashSethia",
        linkedinId: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/yash-sethia-852206191/" 
    }
]

export default user
```

Here is **App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import data from './data/data.js'
import './App.css';
import { Component } from 'react';
import ProfileIntroduction from './Profile Intro/profileIntro';

class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state= {
      
    };
  }

  render() {
    const userPortfolioInfo = data.map(item => <ProfileIntroduction key={item.id} userInfo={item}/>)
    return (
      <div className="main-body">
          {userPortfolioInfo}
          <articleGrid />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Now as you can see, data.js contains the path to 2 differnt images i.e the coverImage and displayPicture. But when I access my prop in te child component profileIntro.js, everything would work fine except for these two images which would not render. **I read online that I need to import the images that I am using in my react App, but I am nopt sure how I can do that if the image is being passed to the child component as a prop. I want the image I want to display would be returned to me from a database and that is why I am implementing it in this way instead of simply importing it.****

Here is my **profileIntro.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import facebook from "../images/facebook.png"
import linkedin from "../images/linkedin.png"
import twitter from "../images/twitter.png";

function profileIntroduction(props) {

    // This function gets a object userInfo as a prop from App.js

    return (
        <div className="profile-intro">
            
            {console.log(props.userInfo)}

            {/* Cover Image */}

            <div className="profile-cover">
                <img className="cover-image" src={props.userInfo.coverImage} alt="" />
            </div>

            {/* Box that contains basic infomation of user */}

            <div className = "flex-container">
                {/* Profile Picture */}
                <img className="profile-img" src={props.userInfo.displayPicture} alt="Profile Picture" />

                {/* User Information */}

                <div className="profile-details">

                    <div className="profile-name">
                        {props.userInfo.name}
                    </div>

                    <div className="profile-bio">
                        {props.userInfo.bio}
                    </div>


                    <div className="profile-location">
                        {props.userInfo.city}, {props.userInfo.country} 
                    </div>


                    <div className="profile-email">
                         CONTACT: <a href="commonstartup@gmail.com"> {props.userInfo.email} </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

                {/* Social Media Handles */}

                <div className="profile-social-media">

                    <a href={props.userInfo.facebookId}> 
                        <img className="social-links"  src={facebook} alt="Facebook" />
                    </a>

                    <a href={props.userInfo.twitterId} > 
                        <img className="social-links" src={twitter} alt="Twitter" />
                    </a>

                    <a href={props.userInfo.linkedinId}> 
                        <img className="social-links"  src={linkedin} alt="LinkedIn" />
                    </a>
                    
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    );
}


export default profileIntroduction
```

I recently startied using react and I am still learning so it would be helpful if you could explain what I was doing wrong exactly in a bit deapth.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `src` property to set image path, you should move your `images` folder from `src` to `public`, and change the relative path of images in the `data.js` to absolute path (remove the starting `.` from the path). That way, react server will be able to resolve image paths when you run application. Also, you do not need then to import images in your source code.

Comment: I did read about this method online but the thing is that, I have not implemented the backend of this. Ideally I'll get the data.js file from my database as a json file. That's why placing the images folder in public would not resolve the issue since the images would be stored in my database and not the public folder.
Also is there any other way to render images in a child component except for using the `src` property ?